# How to avoid CGDisplayModeCopyPixelEncoding to get BPP?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I need my programm to run on Mac OS 10.5 - 10.7, however some system functions has been deprecated since 10.5. My problem is that `CGDisplayBitsPerPixel` does not exist since 10.6 and the new function which is `CGDisplayModeCopyPixelEncoding` does not work under 10.5.

How can I make my programm available for all those versions of mac os?

I could use some `#ifdef _xxx_` to solve this, but this would mean I need two different builds of my app and I need one.

Here is how I set VideoMode:

1. Getting displayID
2. Getting All available modes and push 'em to VideoModeList
3. Getting screen width, height and bpp

Code sample:

```
VideoModeList->setDesktop(rect(screen_w, screen_h), screen_bpp);
VideoModeList->setEffectiveDesktop(rect(screen_w, screen_h), screen_bpp);
```

UPD (Since new users can't post answers to their own questions for 8 hours):
I think I've finaly found the way to do that. I've avoided `CGDisplayBitsPerPixel`instead. Here is a code smaple:

```
// That's how you know what OS you are dealing with in runtime instead of compiletime
bool macOSX_10_6_orHigher = (CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes != NULL);

if (macOSX_10_6_orHigher)
{
  // This function uses CGDisplayModeCopyPixelEncoding and CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode
  // to determine BPP.
  screenBPP = getDisplayBitsPerPixel(displayID);
}
else
{
  // This function in deprecated, bit it is still there, so you will get a warning
  // instead of error
  CFDictionaryRef = currentDisplayMode = CGDisplayCurrentMode(mode);
  CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(currentDisplayMode, kCGDisplayBitsPerPixel), kCFNumberIntType, &screenBPP);
}
```

P.S. If you would like to suggest another solution, I'm still following the topic and we can get a discussion.
P.P.S. Thanks for your interest to this question and thanks to admin who corrected my 1-st post.

Answer (score 2):

New functions CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode and CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes are known to return CGDisplayModeRef.
And I was surprised that the API does not provide a straight function to get BitsPerPixel.
Bye the way CGDisplayModeCopyPixelEncoding has deprecated in OS X v10.11.

Then I disassembled CGDisplayModeGetWidth and saw how the parameter obtained from the CGDisplayModeRef (short):

```
movq   0x10(%rdi), %rdi          ; get CFDictionaryRef from CGDisplayModeRef
leaq   -0x103fd9f2(%rip), %rsi   ; @"Width"
callq  0x7fff8812570e            ; symbol stub for: CFDictionaryGetValue
```

I know it looks awful, and Apple can change API at any time but for now I can get any of params from mode dictionary:

```
CGDisplayModeRef mode = CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode(display);
CFDictionaryRef dict = (CFDictionaryRef)*((int64_t *)mode + 2);
CFNumberRef num;
int bpp;
if (CFGetTypeID(dict) == CFDictionaryGetTypeID()
    && CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(dict, kCGDisplayBitsPerPixel, (const void**)&num))
{
    CFNumberGetValue(num, kCFNumberSInt32Type, (void*)&bpp);
}
CFRelease(mode);
```

Comment: if you've found a cleaner version I'd be interested. :-)

Answer (score 1):

According https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html you can use `__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` like this:

```
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 1050
  screenBPP = DisplayBitsPerPixel (displayID);
#else
  screenBPP = CGDisplayBitsPerPixel (displayID);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I attempted something similar using c++ on MacOS 10.7 using gcc 4.5

```
if (CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes != NULL)
  screenBPP = DisplayBitsPerPixel (displayID); // MacOS > 10.5
else
  screenBPP = CGDisplayBitsPerPixel (displayID);
```

And encountered the error below.

```
error: 'CGDisplayBitsPerPixel' was not declared in this scope
```

Unless Objective-C handles this differently, I don't think your solution will work. To run on 10.5+ you can link directly to the SDK for 10.5 (32 bit only?).  The options below are recommended on the [wxwidgets wiki](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Development%3a_wxMac#Building_on_Snow_Leopard_for_older_versions_of_MacOSX).

```
-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
```

The 10.5 SDK is not part of Xcode 4. Instructions for installing the SDK for MacOS 10.5 on Lion are available [here](http://lunokhod.org/?p=269).